# showing each data from the database

Tags: php, html

[image]

I already show the list of names from the database, but the problem is I don't know how to show the information each user, once I click some user in my list her/his information will appear.

**html**

```
<div class="member_list">
    <div class="list-unstyled">
        <?php require_once "../function/admin_function.php"; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="information" id="table_information">
    <table class="table_information">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Information</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>lastname</th>
            <th>address</th>
            <th>contact</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php include "../function/information_function.php"; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**information_function - php**

```
<?php 
include "../connection/connection.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM registration";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['contact'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

**user list - php**

```
<?php 
include "../connection/connection.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM registration";
$result = mysqli_query ($dbconn, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
    echo "<ul class='table_php'>";
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<a href='#table_information' class='friends_link'>";                  
    echo "<span class='chat-img pull-left'>";
    echo "<img src='user.png' class='img-circle'>"; 
    echo "</span>" . $row['lname'] . "</a>";
    echo "</li>";           
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

Comment: you can use javascript onclick function.and inside function definition you call call ajax  and fetch details

Comment: refer to this question [how-to-get-row-id-in-button-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526475/how-to-get-row-id-in-button-click)
and [how-to-get-the-row-id-of-html-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274721/how-to-get-the-row-id-of-html-table)

Comment: i call the ajax to fetch the data from the php?

Comment: can you give me an example of codes?

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside a function and just call that function after include statement.

//information_function//

```
<?php 
 include "../connection/connection.php";
function get_information(){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM registration";
 $result = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sql);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)){


  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['contact'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

  }
}
  ?>
```

//html//

```
<div class="member_list">
  <div class="list-unstyled">
    <?php require_once "../function/admin_function.php"; ?>
  </div>
 </div>

<div class="information" id="table_information">
  <table class="table_information">
   <tr>
    <th colspan="4">Information</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>lastname</th>
    <th>address</th>
    <th>contact</th>
   </tr>


     <?php include "../function/information_function.php"; ?>
 <?php get_information(); ?>

  </table>
 </div>
```